# php calendar first day monday

Tags: php, calendar

how can i change the first day in the first column of weeks into Monday.

here's the code i got from a website, and I've been trying to change the position of the days but still it displays the first day of the week as Sunday. how can i change it to Monday, thanks in advance

```
if(isset($_POST['func']) && !empty($_POST['func'])){
    switch($_POST['func']){
        case 'getCalender':
            getCalender($_POST['year'],$_POST['month']);
            break;
        case 'getEvents':
            getEvents($_POST['date']);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}


/*
 * Get calendar full HTML
 */
function getCalender($year = '',$month = '')
{
    $dateYear = ($year != '')?$year:date("Y");
    $dateMonth = ($month != '')?$month:date("m");
    $date = $dateYear.'-'.$dateMonth.'-01';
    $currentMonthFirstDay = date("N",strtotime($date));
    $totalDaysOfMonth = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,$dateMonth,$dateYear);
    $totalDaysOfMonthDisplay = ($currentMonthFirstDay == 7)?($totalDaysOfMonth):($totalDaysOfMonth + $currentMonthFirstDay);
    $boxDisplay = ($totalDaysOfMonthDisplay <= 35)?35:42;


?>
    <div id="calender_section">
        <h2>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="getCalendar('calendar_div','<?php echo date("Y",strtotime($date.' - 1 Month')); ?>','<?php echo date("m",strtotime($date.' - 1 Month')); ?>');">&lt;&lt;</a>
            <select name="month_dropdown" class="month_dropdown dropdown"><?php  echo getAllMonths($dateMonth); ?></select>
            <select name="year_dropdown" class="year_dropdown dropdown"><?php echo getYearList($dateYear); ?></select>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="getCalendar('calendar_div','<?php echo date("Y",strtotime($date.' + 1 Month')); ?>','<?php echo date("m",strtotime($date.' + 1 Month')); ?>');">&gt;&gt;</a>
        </h2>
        <div id="event_list" class="none"></div>
        <div id="calender_section_top">
            <ul>
                <li>Po</li>
                <li>Út</li>
                <li>St</li>
                <li>Čt</li>
                <li>Pá</li>
                <li>So</li>
                <li>Ne</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="calender_section_bot">
            <ul>
            <?php
                $dayCount = 1;
                for($cb=1;$cb<=$boxDisplay;$cb++){
                    if(($cb >= $currentMonthFirstDay+0  || $currentMonthFirstDay == 7) && $cb <= ($totalDaysOfMonthDisplay)){
                        //Current date
                        $currentDate = $dateYear.'-'.$dateMonth.'-'.$dayCount;
                        $eventNum = 0;
                        //Include db configuration file
                        include 'dbConfig.php';
                        //Get number of events based on the current date
                        $result = $db->query("SELECT title FROM events WHERE date = '".$currentDate."' AND status = 1");
                        $eventNum = $result->num_rows;
                        //Define date cell color
                        if(strtotime($currentDate) == strtotime(date("Y-m-d"))){
                            echo '<li date="'.$currentDate.'" class="grey date_cell">';
                        }elseif($eventNum > 0){
                            echo '<li date="'.$currentDate.'" class="light_sky date_cell">';
                        }else{
                            echo '<li date="'.$currentDate.'" class="date_cell">';
                        }
                        //Date cell
                        echo '<span>';
                        echo $dayCount;
                        echo '</span>';

                        //Hover event popup
                        echo '<div id="date_popup_'.$currentDate.'" class="date_popup_wrap none">';
                        echo '<div class="date_window">';
                        echo '<div class="popup_event">Events ('.$eventNum.')</div>';
                        echo ($eventNum > 0)?'<a href="javascript:;" onclick="getEvents(\''.$currentDate.'\');">view events</a>':'';
                        echo '</div></div>';

                        echo '</li>';
                        $dayCount++;
            ?>
            <?php }else{ ?>
                <li><span>&nbsp;</span></li>
            <?php } } ?>
```